# Proper way to cast 'threadIdx.x's into higher type in CUDA kernel (%lu format in printf malfunctions in the CUDA kernel?)

Tags: c, cuda

I have to access elements of a very large array in CUDA kernels. The size of arrays could be above INT_MAX in some applications.

Essentially those are taking the form of the following.

```
__global__ function(double *dArr) {
  size_t index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  dArr[index * WIDTH] = ...; // WIDTH is 256 or 512.
}
```

To my understanding, CUDA variables such as `threadIdx.x` are `unsigned int` with smaller limits than the usual `uint`.

I am trying to cast these CUDA variables into higher type so that they can be used as an index of the large array.

I have tried some, but still my kernels are not working with large arrays. And I cannot even understand the results from the following simple lines of code (it is not even taking large numbers).

```
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void printIndex() {
  printf("blockIdx.x %lu (%d), blockDim.x %lu (%d), threadIdx.x %lu (%d)\n",
          blockIdx.x, blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
  //printf("blockIdx.x %d, blockDim.x %d, threadIdx.x %d \n", blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x); // this works fine.
}

int main() {
  printIndex<<<2,64>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  unsigned int ui = 1000;
  printf("ui %lu (%d) \n", ui, ui); // this is just for the comparison.

  return 0;
}
```

The reason I chose `%lu` is to mimic a certain type of casting to higher type and the result is quite strange. (When I use `%u`, it works fine)

```
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 0 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 4294967297 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 8589934594 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 12884901891 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 17179869188 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 21474836485 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 25769803782 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 30064771079 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 34359738376 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 38654705673 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 42949672970 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 47244640267 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 51539607564 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 55834574861 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 60129542158 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 64424509455 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 68719476752 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 73014444049 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 77309411346 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 81604378643 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 85899345940 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 90194313237 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 94489280534 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 98784247831 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 103079215128 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 107374182425 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 111669149722 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 115964117019 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 120259084316 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 124554051613 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 128849018910 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 133143986207 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 137438953504 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 141733920801 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 146028888098 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 150323855395 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 154618822692 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 158913789989 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 163208757286 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 167503724583 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 171798691880 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 176093659177 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 180388626474 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 184683593771 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 188978561068 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 193273528365 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 197568495662 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 201863462959 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 206158430256 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 210453397553 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 214748364850 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 219043332147 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 223338299444 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 227633266741 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 231928234038 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 236223201335 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 240518168632 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 244813135929 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 249108103226 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 253403070523 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 257698037820 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 261993005117 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 266287972414 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 4294967297 (64), blockDim.x 270582939711 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 0 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 4294967297 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 8589934594 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 12884901891 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 17179869188 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 21474836485 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 25769803782 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 30064771079 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 34359738376 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 38654705673 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 42949672970 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 47244640267 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 51539607564 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 55834574861 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 60129542158 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 64424509455 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 68719476752 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 73014444049 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 77309411346 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 81604378643 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 85899345940 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 90194313237 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 94489280534 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 98784247831 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 103079215128 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 107374182425 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 111669149722 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 115964117019 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 120259084316 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 124554051613 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 128849018910 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 133143986207 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 137438953504 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 141733920801 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 146028888098 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 150323855395 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 154618822692 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 158913789989 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 163208757286 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 167503724583 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 171798691880 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 176093659177 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 180388626474 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 184683593771 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 188978561068 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 193273528365 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 197568495662 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 201863462959 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 206158430256 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 210453397553 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 214748364850 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 219043332147 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 223338299444 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 227633266741 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 231928234038 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 236223201335 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 240518168632 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 244813135929 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 249108103226 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 253403070523 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 257698037820 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 261993005117 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 266287972414 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
blockIdx.x 0 (64), blockDim.x 270582939711 (0), threadIdx.x 0 (6)
ui 1000 (1000)
```

At the last line I see that `ui` is printed fine with `%lu`, while the prints in the CUDA kernel is very strange. First of all, `%lu` and `%d` casts are not the same when I am dealing with numbers at most 64. Secondly, even `%d` representations are not correct. `blockIdx.x`'s should be 0 or 1.

Where I got lost? To check the `threadIdx.x` stuff with `printf`, what would be the proper way to do? And if I were to cast those into higher type which can potentially get above INT_MAX (or UINT_MAX), what would be the proper way of cast?

I added `c` tag since this is about `printf` in `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct format string for each variable. It is invalid to use the format string for a 64 bit value and pass a 32 bit value. (who knows what kind of out-of-bounds access is performed this way)

The compiler should warn about this.

> argument is incompatible with corresponding format string conversion (expected type "unsigned long" but argument has type "unsigned int")

If you want to print using `%lu`, cast the argument to size_t, i.e. (size_t)threadIdx.x.

To compute the global thread id as 64 bit value, one could use
`size_t id = size_t(threadIdx.x) + size_t(blockIdx.x) * size_t(blockDim.x);`

Comment: In general, which one is preferred between `size_t` and `int64_t` to access large index? It seems that there is no consensus on this, and since `size_t` can be platform dependent I assume it would be better to use `int64_t`. Also I had a personal comment that `int64_t` is faster than `size_t` (but I cannot find the dedicated documents/posts on the performance comparison between them on web, though).

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned and unsigned variables have a defined wrap-around behavior while signed integers would overflow which is undefined behavior. This undefined behavior allows for some compiler optimizations (independent of CPU or GPU).

Comment: This is also mentioned in the [CUDA C++ Best Practices Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#loop-counters-signed-vs-unsigned).

Comment: @SangjunLee The [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es102-use-signed-types-for-arithmetic) also recommend signed times for any arithmetic to avoid bugs. Both CUDA and C++ (STL) make it hard to do so because some interfaces are already defined using unsigned integers (e.g. `dim3` in CUDA, `container.size` in STL) and C++ casts like `static_cast` are verbose by design (to be very visible, searchable and maybe so you try to avoid them when possible).

Comment: @paleonix, yes I have gone through the C++ Core Guidelines, which at the end recommends to use `gsl::index` but I suppose I cannot in CUDA kernel, right? So you are recommending to use 'signed' type such as `int64_t` for `threadIdx.x`'s to be casted into instead of 'size_t`?

Comment: In the end it is just a short alias for `ptrdiff_t` I think. Using type aliases like that in CUDA should be no problem. For general gsl functionality there is also the [gsl-lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) implementation which comes with the needed `__host__ __device__` annotations on some functions.